# Using different variable names

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have an application (with Electron) that uses a lot of videos that activate onclick. Ive been using the following format for them:

```js
     function playvideo1(){
       var video = document.getElementById("video1");
        video.currentTime = 0; 
       video.play();
                 }
     function playvideo2(){
       var video = document.getElementById("video2");
        video.currentTime = 0; 
       video.play();
                 }
```

Is it okay to use "video" for every var name, or should I be using different var names like this?:

```js
         function playvideo1(){
           var video1 = document.getElementById("video1");
            video1.currentTime = 0; 
           video1.play();
                     }
         function playvideo2(){
           var video2 = document.getElementById("video2");
            video2.currentTime = 0; 
           video2.play();
                     }
```

Comment: Why define multiple functions? Just define one `playVideo()` function and make the ID an argument. `playVideo("video1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is okay, so long as your code remains readable and maintainable.

Variables defined with `var` are scoped to the closure in which they are defined.  In other words, the `var video` that you defined in `playvideo1()` does not exist outside of `playvideo1()`.  Therefore it is safe to define a variable called `video` again in `playvideo2()`.

Note that this assumes that there is no variable `video` that exists in any closure that contains your function definitions.

Here's some more information on variable scope in Javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp